# add span class and i tag inside wp_nav_menu link anchor tag

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I found examples adding a class to top level items, so we can display an arrow in menu items with sub-items, but is seems terrible to cope with the already built in WordPress classes, can't display the arrow with current and css hover, it just ruins all states.

The current nav menu is like this `<li><a>Text</a></li>`

Is there someway to add a `<span class="something"><i class="something"></i></span>` within the parent `<a></a>` tags instead?

Example

```
<li class="main-nav__item">
      <a class="main-nav__item-link" href="index.html">
            <span class="main-nav__item-icon-wrapper">
                   <i class="main-nav__item-icon icon-home"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="main-nav__item-content">Home</span>
      </a>
</li>
<li class="main-nav__item">
        <a class="main-nav__item-link" href="index.html">
               <span class="main-nav__item-icon-wrapper">
                     <i class="main-nav__item-icon icon-Blog"></i>
               </span>
               <span class="main-nav__item-content">Blog</span>
        </a>
</li>
```

The current code Adds the  tags outside the  tags that is parent

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"main-nav\">\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wp_nav_menu()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) arguments like so:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'          => 'Whatever Your Menu Name Is',
    'link_before'   => '<span class="main-nav__item-icon-wrapper"><i class="main-nav__item-icon icon-home"></i></span><span class="main-nav__item-content">',
    'link_after'    => '</span>'
) );
```

`link_before` and `*_after` will add anything before/after the text *inside* the link where just the normal argument `before` and `after` will add anything before/after *the entire link* but still inside the list-item.

This will add them to **all** the list items *but* you can use CSS to style them or not display them however you wish and I think it's faster and easier than working with a walker.

Comment: Not working. please solve me using walker.

Comment: @ASMSaief Not working, how? As in it breaks the website or it's not adding it in the correct places?